# what is servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY

Tags: c, sockets

In socket programming what does

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
```

in a client program do actually? What does INADDR_ANY mean?

Also in another source found in the internet, I found

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
```

What is this step doing? I think I have to enter the server ip as argument in that client wants to get connected to. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a server, `INADDR_ANY` is an argument to `bind` that tells the socket to listen on all available interfaces.

On a client, it's an argument to `connect` that tells the client which server to connect to but would appear to be meaningless other than as an alternative way of specifying "this host".

(In both cases it's actually a pointer to a `struct sockaddr_in` that's actually passed, and the IP adderss is the `sin_addr.s_addr` field of that structure.  The formal function specification actually specifies a `struct sockaddr *`)

Comment: Ok thanks, but why is it argv[1], aint this should be argv[0]? because there is no argv[0] in the code then how could it be argv[1]?

Comment: that's standard C/C++ - `argv[0]` is the name of the program itself, `argv[1]` is therefore the first supplied parameter.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot friend. learnt something new and useful!

Comment: The `INADDR_ANY` argument to connect makes sense only when an op is learns socket programming where the client and server happens to be in the same host. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384694/sockets-using-inaddr-any-on-client-side#comment34030152_22384827) comment says giving INADDR_ANY an argument to `connect` is not a standard practice, though no links to substantiate the claim is provided.

Comment: On a client it is meaningless except as a local bind address. It certainly can't be used as a connect target address. I have never seen any evidence that it works.

Comment: @EJP But it does work as a local bind as already stated by you. `htonl(INADDR_ANY)` could be used when by the op when  they learn socket programming, ie when the client and server is on the same host. Apart from that I don't see a use case.